# MYSQL filter for 200 Fields/Columns

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, laravel, filter

I am tasked by a client (A mortgage/real estate company) to make a form that inserts over 200 fields in the database. I have done that by heavily normalizing the database for this form and I currently have 82 tables.
I am able to post the data correctly. 
**Problem**
I am supposed to make a search filter that allows him to play around with any of the 200 fields and give matching results.
This is by far the most challenging task I ever undertook because I plainly dont know how to achieve this.
I have javascript on the front end and laravel in the backend.
Below is my attempt of the search with the first 6 fields which will then need to expanded somehow to include all the other database fields in different table.
As it is, even the 6 dont search well because:

1. I have many comma separated values in the fields of some search tables (This was the only way since some records have 20k values so cant be put in a different table)
2. The search dropdowns also have comma separated values
   This makes it difficult to make use of FIND_IN_SET esp where the search term contains more than 1 value e.g 1,2
   Below is the piece of code I am using for the search

   ```
    function search(Request $request){

    $property_type          = $request->property_type;
    $property_type_value    = $request->property_type_value;
    $application_purpose    = $request->application_purpose;
    $property_style         = $request->property_style;
    $application_type       = $request->application_type;
    $product_province       = $request->product_province;
    $product_region         = $request->product_region;
    $product_county         = $request->product_county;
    $product_city           = $request->product_city;

    $products = DB::table('lender_product_types as prod')
                    ->join('property_types as ptype', DB::raw('FIND_IN_SET(ptype.id,prod.prodproperty_type)'),'>',DB::raw('0')  )
                    ->join('property_type_values as ptypev', DB::raw('FIND_IN_SET(ptypev.id,prod.prodproperty_type_value)'),'>',DB::raw('0')  )
                    ->join('application_purposes as app', DB::raw('FIND_IN_SET(app.id,prod.application_purpose)'),'>',DB::raw('0')  )
                    ->join('property_styles as pss', DB::raw('FIND_IN_SET(pss.id,prod.property_style)'),'>',DB::raw('0')  )
                    ->join('application_types as ats', DB::raw('FIND_IN_SET(ats.id,prod.application_type)'),'>',DB::raw('0')  )
                    ->whereIn('prod.prodproperty_type',array($property_type) )
                    ->whereIn('prod.prodproperty_type_value',array($property_type_value) )
                    ->whereIn('prod.application_purpose',array($application_purpose) )
                    ->whereIn('prod.property_style',array($property_style) )
                    ->whereIn('prod.application_type',array($application_type) )
                    ->select('prod.id',
                        'ptype.*',DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(ptype.description ORDER BY ptype.id) ptype_desc'),
                        'ptypev.*',DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(ptypev.description ORDER BY ptypev.id) ptypev_desc'),
                        'app.*',DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(app.description ORDER BY app.id) app_desc'),
                        'pss.*',DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(pss.description ORDER BY pss.id) pss_desc'),
                        'ats.*',DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(ats.description ORDER BY ats.id) ats_desc')
                    )
                    ->groupBy('prod.id')
                    ->get();
    if($products) {
        $returnHTML = view('filter_searchload', compact('products'))->render();

        //Return a success code
        $response = array('status' => '200',
            'message' => 'Data retrieved successfully',
            'html' => $returnHTML
        );

        return Response::json($response);
    }
    else{
        //Return a success code
        $response = array('status' => '500',
            'message' => 'Error Retrieving data',
        );

        return Response::json($response);
    }
   ```

   }

Below is an example of the 3 tables that we can work with then I can extend the knowledge to other tables.
**Main Search Table- Columns underlined are linked to records in other tables**

[image: Main Search Table- Columns underlined are linked to records in other tables]

**prodproperty_type_value table... a property can have multiple features from this table**
[image: prodproperty_type_value table... a property can have multiple features from this table]

**prodproperty_style table ... a property can have multiple features from this table**
[image: prodproperty_style table ... a property can have multiple features from this table]

**Sample search page with just a few fields ... will be expanded to 200 fields somehow**
[image: Sample search page with just a few fields ... will be expanded to 200 fields somehow]

Just point me to the right direction on how to do it, I will do the rest of the hard work kindly.

Comment: I see comma separated values in your relationships. That doesn't look normalised to me

Comment: @apokryfos This had to be done that way as explained since some table records like cities have 20k records and we allow users to multiselect so if we allowed even 10 users to select all cities, the 10 records would translate to 200k records in one table. So I opted for comma separated values. I hope it makes sense

Comment: I think you'll find all those uses of `FIND_IN_SET()` are far worse for query optimization than allowing the table to grow to 200k rows. FWIW, MySQL can handle tables with _billions_ of rows.

Comment: @Bill Karwin at the moment, even those FIND_IN_SET are not working well. ... what route would you advice me to follow?

Comment: Properly normalise your entities if you are going relational or opt for a NoSQL like MongoDB database if that would make things easier for you

Comment: @apokryfos I think you and Bill Karwin are right .. Lemme restructure and remove those comma separated values then hope for the best. Thank you very much